# Is it possible to insert records to MySQL with different parameter (keys & values) each time using the same insert function in Java?

Tags: java, php, mysql, function, multiple-records

I am trying to find out if it is possible to use the same insert function each time with new different parameters in java 8 & MySQL. I know it is possible in PHP as I have the PHP code below :

this is the array records:

```
$Customer_details=[
             'firstname' => $Firstname,
             'lastname'=> $lastname,
             'phone'  => $phone,
             'email'  => $email,
             'password'=> $hash

  ];
```

After created the class object which is $object2 this is the records:

```
$object2->insert($pdo,'customer',$Customer_details);
```

The following code is the PHP insert function code:

```
function insert( $pdo, $table, $record) {
$keys = array_keys( $record);
$values = implode( ', ' , $keys);
$valuesWithColon = implode( ', :' , $keys);
$query = 'INSERT INTO '  . $table . ' ('  . $values . ') VALUES (:'  . 
$valuesWithColon . ')' ;
$stmt = $pdo->prepare( $query);
$stmt->execute( $record);
return $stmt;
}
```

Can anybody just show me an example of the same thing in java, Please?

Comment: Check prepared statements.

Comment: I had a look at it, but I could not find if there is any way to use an array of keys and values just like the one that I showed in the PHP code example ($Customer_details) array. @lexicore

Comment: Here is an example: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that in much the same way you would achieve it with php, as @lexicore commented, a common pattern for parameterised sql queries in Java is to use [PreparedStatements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Here is an example.. you would just need to wrap the code in that example in a function to make it reusable like your php example..
https://alvinalexander.com/java/java-mysql-insert-example-preparedstatement

```
public void insert(String fname, String lname, Date created, boolean isAdmin, int points) {
    String myDriver = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";
    String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";
    Class.forName(myDriver);
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "root", "");

    // create a sql date object so we can use it in our INSERT statement
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    java.sql.Date startDate = new java.sql.Date(calendar.getTime().getTime());

    // the mysql insert statement
    String query = " insert into users (first_name, last_name, date_created, is_admin, num_points)"
      + " values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    // create the mysql insert preparedstatement
    PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    preparedStmt.setString (1, fname);
    preparedStmt.setString (2, lname);
    preparedStmt.setDate   (3, created);
    preparedStmt.setBoolean(4, isAdmin);
    preparedStmt.setInt    (5, points);

    // execute the preparedstatement
    preparedStmt.execute();

    conn.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In your example, they are using this code  `String query = " insert into users (first_name, last_name, date_created, is_admin, num_points)" + " values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";` . If just notice, they are using a fixed keys which I dont want. I am looking for a way that I could change the keys each time.

Comment: You would just need to replace those fixed strings with variables, i've updated my answer with a code snippet!

Comment: That will strict the number of keys and values which means that I couldn't send a different number of keys and values to the same function. Therefore, I need to create a new function for every update statement. @stephen

Comment: Did you understand my question?

Comment: Ah, ok, i see what you mean, what you would need to do is pass a Map such as a HashMap as a parameter rather than fixed parameters. A HashMap contains key value pairs and  you could iterate this map to build your query..this is how you would iterate the map: `for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Object value = entry.getValue();
    // ...
}`

Comment: Can you please do me a favour and show me in an example of the insertion  function to MySQL? @stephen

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this about a year ago, but I think this is what your looking for.

Ibelieve youwant to changeValuesto `List<Object` and use a switch statement with `instanceOf`to parse through that.

```
private String insert(String tableName, List<String> columns, List<String> values){
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (");
    for(String column :columns){
        stringBuilder.append(column + ",");
    }
    stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(stringBuilder.lastIndexOf(","));
    stringBuilder.append(") VALUES (");
    for(String value : values){
        stringBuilder.append(value + ",");
    }
    stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(stringBuilder.lastIndexOf(","));
    stringBuilder.append(")");
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Of as previously mention use this and make the second loop:

```
for(int z =0; z < columns.size(); z++){
    stringBuilder.append("?,");
}
```

To use with `PreparedStatements` knowing what I know now, I would choose the latter.